# change background color different text in table html

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a table in html and i need to change the color of backgrund in the 
i have a tow diffrent word in this 
normal or high
for normal i need a yello bgcolor
for high i need a red bgcolor
i need to do this in css or javascript?

this is my simple code:

```
<tr>
<td class='tg-yw4l'></td>
<td class='tg-s6z2'></td>
<td class='tg-s6z2'></td>
<td class='tg-baqh' rowspan='2'></td>
<td class='tg-baqh' rowspan='2'>Normal Different</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: just a text normal text

Comment: I can't understand your question,what is normal or high

Comment: this is a text inside the <td> <td class='tg-baqh' rowspan='2'>Normal Different</td> once is normal and once it's can be high

Comment: @Tzahi What is the high one?

Comment: what library i need to use?

Comment: Some punctuation would make the question much more readable.

Comment: You can do that in CSS or Javascript, it deppends on the moment you want to change the color. If you want it from the beggining, use simple CSS, else use Javascript.
By the way, your question is not very clear.

Comment: Must the word `Normal` have a yellow background and the word `Different` have a red background?

Comment: First you should learn how to ask questions on stackoverflow...

Comment: I really want to give @Vi100 a thumbs up

Comment: sorry my english is not the best now the html code was build in c# code and i dont know what the line so i want to do somthing is chaek if the text in td is normal the backgroun is yello if the text in td is high the backgroun color is red i hope i explain better now

Comment: You should use javascript to go through this whole table, and maybe use <span class ="css"> to surround the words you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand your question exactly, but I do hope that this is helpful.
this is a js sample ( In my point of view, generate by serverside is more easier  )

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td class='tg-yw4l'></td>
 <td class='tg-s6z2'></td>
 <td class='tg-s6z2'></td>
 <td class='tg-baqh' rowspan='2'></td>
 <td class='tg-baqh bg' rowspan='2'>Normal</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.red{background-color:red}
.yellow{background-color:yellow}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $('.bg').each( function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if( $this.text() == "Normal" ) {
            $this.addClass("red");
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create two css classes

```
.red{color:red}
.yellow{color:yellow}
```

And when creating the table, just wrap the word in a span and add the relevant class

```
<span class='red'>High</span>
```

Comment: i need the class for other use

Comment: What do you mean? The class can be called anything, my suggestion is basically to wrap the words that need their color changed in a span with some identifying css class name

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know how to do this would be to take your class and use a CSS stylesheet. Use something like this at the top of your html page to link the external stylesheet.

```
<link href= "file location" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Then go to the stylesheet you have created and enter the name of your class after a dot and enter something like this

```
.classname
{
background-color:red;
}
```

This way you can always add more formatting to your classes. You can also look up the code to all sorts of colors online.